# What order did people get badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've noticed a few SO profiles where people have listed "35th to get the gold C badge" or something along those lines.  If I didn't go look on the day I got a particular badge, is there a way to find out what my place is in that lineup?

Comment: Count. The badge holders are listed chronologically. (From newest to oldest.)

Comment: Yeah, I had guessed that, but I was hoping for an easier way, should one exist.

Comment: Aw, come on, counting to 13 isn't that hard.

Comment: To 13?  Am I missing something?  Also, rows first or columns?

Comment: You got your gold C badge [on September 22, 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116908/carl-norum?tab=activity&sort=badges&page=9). I don't remember whether rows or columns come first offhand, but using that date lookup method you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: On page 2, there's just litb. Your name is the leftmost of four in the third row from the bottom. `1 + 3*4 = 13`.

Comment: @Daniel - gotcha. I didn't get that you were referencing my C badge.  Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to query for this information using [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), which shows you as the 143rd person to be [awarded the gold C++ tag badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/92674?Badge=c%2B%2B&Rank=3&UserId=116908)*.

Additionally, for reference purposes, the [list of badge awardees](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/49/c?userid=116908) goes across the page and then down.

<sub>*The linked query is a little restricted in the sense that you can only get your rank for the highest level of the badge you've been awarded, but you could rewrite it to give you each level</sub>